# PostgreSQL Query Results : Visual Studio Code vs. pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, pgadmin

I'm fairly new to the SQL world and have been learning by reading Practical SQL by Anthony DeBarros. In the book he uses pgAdmin for all the queries but I am used to having everything done on Visual Studio Code  - I like the autocomplete function on VSC and understand the layout pretty well...

My question is: The query results in VSC differ in formatting from pgAdmin. For example, in VSC I get the following query result

[image: VSC Query Result]

but in pgAdmin, as is noted in the book, is the following:

[image: pgAdmin Query Result]

The 'segment' column's values are easier to understand than in the VSC results.

The code to create the table and data is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE train_rides (
trip_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
segment text NOT NULL,
departure timestamptz NOT NULL,
arrival timestamptz NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO train_rides (segment, departure, arrival)
VALUES
('Chicago to New York', '2020-11-13 21:30 CST', '2020-11-14 18:23 EST'),
('New York to New Orleans', '2020-11-15 14:15 EST', '2020-11-16 19:32 CST'),
('New Orleans to Los Angeles', '2020-11-17 13:45 CST', '2020-11-18 9:00 PST'),
('Los Angeles to San Francisco', '2020-11-19 10:10 PST', '2020-11-19 21:24 PST'),
('San Francisco to Denver', '2020-11-20 9:10 PST', '2020-11-21 18:38 MST'),
('Denver to Chicago', '2020-11-22 19:10 MST', '2020-11-23 14:50 CST');

SET TIME ZONE 'US/Central';

SELECT * FROM train_rides;
```

For the query, I used this code:

```
SELECT segment,
   to_char(departure, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI a.m. TZ') AS departure,
   arrival - departure AS segment_duration
FROM train_rides;
```

So the question is: why do they look different? Is it a formatting thing in VSC? I would much rather use VSC than pgAdmin for my queries as I stated before.

Comment: Yes, it's only a formatting thing, they represent exactly the same values.

Comment: Btw, pgAdmin provides schema-based autocompletion as well

Comment: I know it represents the same values but it would be better, for visualization purposes, to view it in the style that pgAdmin does it but in the VSC interface......IF possible?

Comment: You might try `(arrival - departure)::text AS segment_duration`